# Utility function: NA value validation in R

Tags: r, data-analysis, na

I am trying to write a function to validate the NA values for a target column for a dataframe.

if I run the code outside the function it is working fine. and returning TRUE, but not when I am trying to put the code inside a function.

I nail down the issue I printed both naCount and notNaCount and both are returning the same Value, it is something to do with variable scoping?

I am very new to R. Looks like I am missing something fundamentally. can anyone help me what am I doing wrong?

```
validate_NA_Values<- function(referenceNonNAColumn,targetColumn)
{
  naCount <-length(which(is.na(targetColumn)))
  #print(naCount)
  notNaCount <-length(!which(is.na(targetColumn)))
  #print(notNaCount)
  return(length(referenceNonNAColumn) == naCount+notNaCount)
}
```

I missed the 
**!** which(is.na(targetColumn) that is the root cause.

To understand that I have used the following ,

```
library("missForest")
mtcars.sim.miss<- mtcars 
mtcars.sim.miss["simulatedMissinghp"] <- prodNA(data.frame(mtcars$hp),noNA= 
0.3)

length(which(is.na(mtcars.sim.miss$simulatedMissinghp)))
length(which(!is.na(mtcars.sim.miss$simulatedMissinghp)))
```

Comment: Please show an example of how you are using the function, and maybe a sample input. But I think you want to move the `!` *inside* the `which`. You want to be negating the logical result of `is.na()`, not the integer value results of `which`.

Comment: Thanks Gregor.Yes I missed that.

Comment: First, as already mentioned twice, the problem is the wrong order of the !which(...), where you need to place the inversion INSIDE the which.

Second, you might want to use the debugging functionality of RStudio. Whenever I hae such a problem, I insert a browser() as the first line of the function and run a test call. RStudio will stop evaluation there and you can step through each line or even evaluate single pieces of your calls. In your case, evaluate `is.na(targetColumn)`, `which(is.na(targetColumn)` and `!which(is.na(targesColumn))` and you will quickly see where the problem lies...

Comment: @Reinhold Kainhofer : thanks for the browser() option. it is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is the problem:

```
notNaCount <-length(!which(is.na(targetColumn)))
```

That's a logical vector, which will be all `FALSE` and exactly as long as the elements of `targetColumn` that are not `NA`.

Illustration:

```
x <- c(1, 1, NA, 1, NA)
which(is.na(x))

[1] 3 5

!which(is.na(x))
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

I think you want `which(!is.na(x))` which in my example returns `[1] 1 2 4`